# How to have optional resources with Serverless framework on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, resources, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

**Question:** what's the best way to have optional resources on a Serverless framework based Lambda?

I want to let Serverless cares about resources that the Lambda needs on lower environments (dev, test, staging), and have independent ones for higher environments, like production.

I was thinking about using something like

```yml
resources: 
    Resources: ${file(../${self:provider.stage}-resources.yml)}
```

my resources yml is like the following:

```yml
SQSQueue:
  Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
  Properties:
    QueueName: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-queue

SNSTopic:
  Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
  Properties:
    DisplayName: TEST SNS Topic
    TopicName: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-topic

SNSSubscription:
  Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
  Properties:
      Endpoint: mail@email.com
      Protocol: email
      TopicArn: { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["arn:aws:sns:${self:provider.region}:", { "Ref" : "AWS::AccountId" }, ":${self:resources.Resources.SNSTopic.Properties.TopicName}" ] ]  }
```

But it's not working. Any ideas on what's the best practice to achieve that?

Comment: that seems to be right, I'm doing something similar. Did the cloudformation stack json added your variables? could you share the structure of one of your `stage-resource.yml`?

Comment: What's inside your `*-resources.yml` file?

Comment: @dege I've updated my questions with some more info. The problem is, when I try to deploy it like that, it get stucked, doing anything.

Comment: sorry @abierto can't see the problem, by any chance are you trying to access a file with the wrong path? did you tried setting up a custom variable on your serverless.yml  and used before going to external file?

Comment: @dege as I can see, if I only load the queue and the topic everything is fine. When I try to also load the subscription, it's not working.

Comment: @dege I've isolated the problem: looks like the TopicArn, written that way doesn't work. But I don't know how to dynamically create it without that syntax...

Comment: did you tried using a function in a js file instead of a yaml? the function could receive your arguments

Comment: you have an example here https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#reference-variables-in-javascript-files

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The description in the question focuses on getting all resources in a single resource file, and use different such files per stage. This works, but has the limitation that you must put at least one resource in each stage. And also forces you to group together resources.

Another way to include optional resources that I used in `serverless.yml` is as follows:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}

resources:
  - ${file(./sls-resources/mandatory-resource.yml)}
  - ${file(./sls-resources/optional-resource.${self:provider.stage}.yml), ''}
```

Then, you only create `optional-resource.prod.yml` to hold your production-only resource. When generating the template for dev stage, serverless resolves the optional reference to an empty element because the file does not exist, and then just ignores it.

Note I used the stage variable just as example, but it can be any other variable, e.g. region or a custom variable.

Answer (score 3):

Replacing this:

```
TopicArn: { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["arn:aws:sns:${self:provider.region}:", { "Ref" : "AWS::AccountId" }, ":${self:resources.Resources.SNSTopic.Properties.TopicName}" ] ]
```

with this:

```
TopicArn: {"Ref" : "SNSTopic"}
```

Fixed my issue.

Comment: I'm glad that  found a solution :)